# Angular, markup binding variable as index of another variable

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I would like to know if it is possible with AngularJs to render an array element by using another scrop variable as the index like :
{{array[{{index}}]}}.

For example I am trying to achieve this (note the nested {{}} ) :

```
<ion-item collection-repeat="item in prodataSelect" collection-item-height="52">
  <img class="imageoptionsbrand" src={{imagesUrls[{{item.brand | lowercase | nospace}}+'.png']}} />
</ion-item>
```

Both `prodataSelect` and `imagesUrls` are in the scope of the view in controller.js :

```
angular.module('SnowBoard.controllers', ['SnowBoard.services'])
.controller('ComputeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, sessionService) {
  $scope.prodataSelect = [];
  prodata = sessionService.get('prodata');
  $scope.prodataSelect = prodata;
  $scope.imagesUrls = sessionService.get('imagesUrls');
})
```

The array imagesUrls is as follows:

```
 Object {
 byrne.png: "./img/brands/byrne.png"
 byrne.pngtype: "brand"
 owenwright.png: "./img/pros/owenwright.png"
 owenwright.pngtype: "pro"
 BX2.png: "./img/boards/BX2.png"
 BX2.pngtype: "board"
 BlakBox2.jpg: "./img/boards/BlakBox2.jpg"
 BlakBox2.jpgtype: "board"
 CI-girabbit.png: "./img/boards/CI-girabbit.png"
 CI-girabbit.pngtype: "board"
 ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.
Try removing the curly braces @ item and maybe also remove the .png or add it after the retrieved image name?

```
 <img class="imageoptionsbrand" ng-src={{imagesUrls[{{item.brand | lowercase | nospace}}]+'.png']}} />
```

to

```
  <img class="imageoptionsbrand" ng-src="{{imagesUrls[(item.brand | lowercase | nospace) + '.png']}}"] />
```

To show you that it is possible check this quick example that I've put together

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8GtRKlsOXPTZPWlTUGXl?p=preview)

Comment: Hi @muller, thanks a lot. But the problem is that ".png" is included in the imagesUrls array so I have to pass it by any means. Do you see a solution ?